# How to pass props data to compose()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I have Messages component that uses firebase and connects to store,
now i am struggling with how to set  queryParams: limitToLast dynamically, passing data from props dose not work.. Any idea?

The error i recive is: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { compose } from 'redux'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { firebaseConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

    class Messages extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.props.active ? (
              this.props.message.map(x => console.log(x))
            ) : (
              <span>Loading</span>
            )}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    // Checks prop type and outputs to console if type not matched..
    Messages.propTypes = {
      Messages: PropTypes.array
    }


    export default compose(
      firebaseConnect([
        {
          path: 'message',
          queryParams: ['limitToLast=' this.props.count]
        }
      ]),
      //connect to redux store
      connect(({ firebase: { ordered, profile } }) => ({
        message: ordered.message,
        uid: profile.uid
      }))
    )(Messages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned within the [docs](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase), you can access the props like this:

```
firebaseConnect(props => {
// Set listeners based on props (prop is route parameter from react-router in this case)
return [
  { path: `todos/${props.params.todoId}` } // create todo listener
  // `todos/${props.params.todoId}` // equivalent string notation
]
```

}),

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps you:

```
import { compose } from 'redux' 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'

export default compose(
  firestoreConnect((props) => [
    { collection: 'todos', doc: props.todoId } // or `todos/${props.todoId}`
  ]),

  connect(({ firestore: { data } }, props) => ({
    todos: data.todos && data.todos[todoId]
  }))
)(SomeComponent)
```